# What will be the issue when crash log contains _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, crashlytics, tvos

Below I have given the crash log from crashlytics, no other information available.On checking the logs, the issue occurs at different scenarios each time. Could not replicate the issue. Could anyone help me out to analyse the issue in Apple tvos application.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
SIGTRAP 0x0000000....

0
InsightAgentTVOS
(Missing)
1
InsightAgentTVOS
(Missing)
2
InsightAgentTVOS
(Missing)
3
InsightAgentTVOS
(Missing)
4
InsightAgentTVOS
(Missing)
5
InsightAgentTVOS
(Missing)
3
   libdispatch.dylib
  _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
  4
  libdispatch.dylib
  _dispatch_client_callout + 16
  5
  libdispatch.dylib
  _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 872
  6
  CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
  7
  CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun + 2480
  8
  CoreFoundation
  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
  9
  GraphicsServices
  GSEventRunModal + 160
  10
  UIKitCore
  -[UIApplication _run] + 1060
  11
  UIKitCore
  UIApplicationMain + 164
```

Comment: @rob updated with few more details, only this much details in call stack. Any guess on the issue?.

Comment: I assume that InsightAgentTVOS is the library from Rapid7? Since the entire stack is either their code or Apple's, it's almost certainly in their code. If you configure their framework by passing it objects or closures, it could be in your code, but it doesn't look like that. In any case, if they are unable to work with you (even if it's your bug), you need to reconsider whether the framework is worth it. There's nothing here for us to help you with, however. "It crashed while a dispatch block was being executed" tells us nothing at all. The answer is in the (missing) frames.

Answer (score 3):

The `_dispatch_call_block_and_release` is almost certainly not the issue (though it suggests that the underlying probably might be in some block that you dispatched with GCD). The `SIGTRAP` is suggests that the problem may be [Swift runtime error](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_crashes_from_swift_runtime_errors), such as forced unwrapping/casting. For general overview of crash reports, refer to [Analyzing a Crash Report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/analyzing_a_crash_report).

FYI, the “(Missing)” might suggest that is this code was was not symbolicated or the wrong compilation options. When it’s built correctly, the crash reports show you the exact line number in one’s code. That eliminates the guesswork.

---

Above, I assumed that `InsightAgentTVOS` was your code. If not, as Rob Napier surmised, then the problem is undoubtedly in their library. Perhaps some required parameter was not supplied. (Forced unwrapping of some optional value is a common source of this sort of problem.) If you don’t find the issue, I’d suggest you open a ticket with them, providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: could not get much details regarding reason for crash. Anyway will check the thirdparty library for any memory leaks. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, a memory leak would not be my first guess. I would suspect either (a) some misuse of their API, e.g., some required parameter/property was not provided; or (b) a bug in their code. But they will undoubted offer better guidance.